# How i can aggregate object of data with rxjs?

Tags: angular, typescript, aggregation

I have an object of activity with this structure:

```
export class Activity {
  id?: number;
  hours: number;
  date: string;
  employee: ActivityEmployee;
  type: ActivityType;
  project?: ActivityProject;
}
```

Now I want aggregate data for project, so when i will choose "project" in drop-down element, i want see for every project the total hours about activity.

For example i have this table:

> John Smit Project ProjectName1    4 hours
>
> John Loucs    Project ProjectName1    4 hours
>
> John Bilton Project ProjectName1  4 hours
>
> John Smit Project ProjectName2    4 hours
>
> John Smit Project ProjectName2    4 hours

I would return this:

> ProjectName1  12 hours
>
> ProjectName2  8 hours

Actually i do only a filter with this code:

```
export function activitiesFilterFn(
  entities: Activity[],
  { query }: { query: string }
): Activity[] {
  return query
    ? entities.filter(
        (e) =>
          -1 <
            e.employee.firstName.toLowerCase().indexOf(query.toLowerCase()) ||
          -1 < e.employee.lastName.toLowerCase().indexOf(query.toLowerCase()) ||
          -1 < e.type.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(query.toLowerCase()) ||
          -1 < e.project?.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(query.toLowerCase()) ||
          -1 <
            e.project?.customer.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(query.toLowerCase())
      )
    : entities;
}
```

EDIT:

```
export function activitiesFilterFn(
  entities: Activity[],
  { query, aggregator }: { query: string, aggregator: string}
): any {
  return query && !aggregator
    ? entities.filter(
        (e) =>
          -1 <
            e.employee.firstName.toLowerCase().indexOf(query.toLowerCase()) ||
          -1 < e.employee.lastName.toLowerCase().indexOf(query.toLowerCase()) ||
          -1 < e.type.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(query.toLowerCase()) ||
          -1 < e.project?.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(query.toLowerCase()) ||
          -1 <
            e.project?.customer.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(query.toLowerCase())
      )
    : aggregator
    ? entities.reduce((acc,activity)=>{
     
      
      acc[activity.project.customer.id]=acc[activity.project.customer.id]+activity.hours;
      return acc;
    }, {})
    : entities;
}
```

Comment: Could you please add some codes, so we can help you to achieve that?

Comment: ok, i add how i do filtering

Comment: use `Array#reduce`

Comment: project is OPTIONAL in your case, so activity.project.customer throws error when project is not set.

Comment: You are adding `undefined + number` which will result in `NaN`. This is not how I wrote my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Array#reduce` to aggregate counters

```
   activities:Activity[] = yourFuncWithFilters();
   
  const aggregated=activities.reduce((acc,activity)=>{
    const projectName = activity?.project.name ?? 'NO PROJECT'; 
    if(acc[projectName]===undefined){
      acc[projectName] = 0;
    } 
    acc[projectName]=acc[projectName]+activity.hours;

   // or above as 1 liner
   // acc[projectName]=(acc[projectName] ?? 0) + activity.hours;
    return acc;
  },{});
```

This should result in object like

```
{
  "activity1":14,
  "activity2":1
   .....
}
```

and so on. Just keep in mind that `project` is optional in your case, while it is required for aggregation, so I have used a static string to fill the gap (change to whatever that fits you)

Comment: i have a error: ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'customer' of null

i'm editing post with new code i've write.

Comment: well, you have null project.

Comment: ok now work, but i want return an Activity[] object, like entities. How can do?

Comment: `Activity` is not aggregating anything, so either you want to aggregate your data or not.

Comment: Specify type of required response, then we can have look. Now ` i want return an Activity[] object, like entities.` is less then understandable to me in the given context.

Comment: I want to be returned to me an object of type Activity, where I will have each project and in the hours column the sum of the hours. It doesn't matter if the other fields are empty.

you can see Activity in the start of post.

You can see also the first condition in i do "query? "

Comment: I would like the "reduce" to provide me with the same type of entities, but making projects and hours univocal.